# how this Ternary Operator work with this statemnt?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, conditional-operator, boolean-expression

i just generate this methode to find max val in some matrix and somehowe i was able to change `int`  val insdie  Ternary Operator (java 8)

```
int  max=0, indexToReturn=0;
        int size= arr[0].length;
        for (int i=1 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            //
            //                                                 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            max =  (!(arr[j][indexToReturn] > arr[j][i])) ? indexToReturn= i : arr[j][indexToReturn] ;
        }
     return max > 0 ||  indexToReturn==size-1 ? arr[j][indexToReturn] : null;
```

(the method compile and working)

im not realy sure evan how its compile from what i saw online Ternary Operator  syntax  :

```
variable = Expression1 ? Expression2: Expression3
```

can someone explain me what im missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works is because an assignment is an expression. The value of an assignment is the value assigned. This sounds theoretical, so let us look at an example:

```
int i, k;
i = (k = 5);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(k);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/039ZYY)

The value of the expression `k = 5` is the assigned value `5`. This value is then assigned to `i`.

Armed with this knowledge, we see that `indexToReturn= i` is an expression that evaluates to the value of `i`. When we swap `Expression2` and `Expression3`, the ternary operator breaks because the  `= i` is not evaluated as part of the ternary operator (due to operator precedence). If we set parentheses around `Expression2`, it works as expected.

---

I would discourage using the fact that an assignment is an expression. (Ab)using this fact often leads to hard-to-understand code.